# Tried all ideas to install utorrent

Tags: command-line, utorrent

I have tried all the options I can find on multiple forums to get uTorrent. I need an idiot proof step by step instruction. I have used multiple terminal commands to no avail.

```
wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
```

This is the output I get

```
--2014-04-27 10:05:39--  http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
Resolving download.utorrent.com (download.utorrent.com)... 67.215.233.132
Connecting to download.utorrent.com (download.utorrent.com)|67.215.233.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-04-27 10:05:39 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Try to get a more recent version here: http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux

Comment: Can you explain more in-detail as in what you're trying to achieve?? are you trying to set-up a torrent server or just the client??

Comment: I am just trying to set up the client.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is somehow unavalible for wget but works in download by web browser.
I suggest to download it manually and then do rest of work in terminal. It is another story when you work in console mode only... But you can always download it somewhere and bring it on a flash drive.

or

try to use lynx or other terminal web browser (f.e. links, elinks) and it works just fine:)
(Of course if not avalible try to install it by *sudo apt-get install lynx*)